# Horizontal Nav in HTML5

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have to say that I'm new to Stack Overflow and HTML5. My primary language isn't English. Learning something in other language than my mother tongue language is very difficult, and I didn't find any HTML help aside from the basics like 'what is head, how to use paragraphs', so I had to appropriate code that I have found on the internet. I ended up needing a little help with it.

My issue is that I need to transform this vertical menu below to horizontal one.

---

Here is the code for the menu:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #333;
}
ul {
  background: white;
  border-top: 6px solid hsl(180, 40%, 60%);
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 0;
}
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: inherit;
  float: left;
}
ul li a {
  font: normal 14px/28px Ubuntu;
  color: hsl(180, 40%, 40%);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
}
.ink {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: hsl(180, 40%, 80%);
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: scale(0);
}
.ink.animate {
  animation: ripple 0.65s linear;
}
@keyframes ripple {
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(2.5);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>23432222</a></li>
    <li><a>444444</a></li>
    <li><a>Sample Text</a></li>
    <li><a>342123443</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would be thankful for any help, and sorry for posting kinda silly questions, I just didn't know where to find an answer for this.

Comment: Hi Leis, if you feel your question has been answered, please don't forget to  mark one of the answers as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. If your question hasn't been fully answered, please elaborate so we can further help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a working horizontal version of the menu. The main things I did were to change `display` on your `ul` and `li` to `inline-block`. This makes it so that they line up next to each other instead of on top of each other. Then I removed the `width: 200px` from the `ul` (which was causing the `li` elements to wrap), and set `text-align: center` on the body to get the menu `ul` to be centered.

**Working Live Demo:**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background: #333;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;
    border-top: 6px solid hsl(180, 40%, 60%);
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0;
}
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: inherit;
}
ul li a {
    font: normal 14px/28px Ubuntu;
    color: hsl(180, 40%, 40%);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    user-select: none;
    position: relative;
}
.ink {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background: hsl(180, 40%, 80%);
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform: scale(0);
}
.ink.animate {
    animation: ripple 0.65s linear;
}
@keyframes ripple {
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(2.5);
    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>23432222</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>444444</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>Sample Text</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>342123443</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/wd51zgog/

Comment: worked for me, thanks, but still there is a small invisible border where the ink effect is activated in menu, that isnt 'affected' with this effect.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to make all the links in-line (horizontal) is to use the CSS attribute `display: inline block;`

```
nav li { 
 display: inline-block;
}
```

The nav is for the nav tags that are used for navigation:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a>23432222</a></li>
      <li><a>444444</a></li>
      <li><a>Sample Text</a></li>
      <li><a>342123443</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```